# Difference in days between 2 columns in MS Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, qliksense, qlik-expression

I am trying to calculate the number of days between two columns. Below is an expression in `qlik sense` that I would like to translate into `DAX`:

```
LPO_DATE - (CLM_INTM_DT) +1
```

I tried this in `DAX` but I don't think it is correct:

```
V_TurnAround_Time =
CALCULATE ( SUM ( LPO_excel[LPO_DATE] ) )
    - CALCULATE ( SUM ( Claims_excel[CLM_INTM_DT] ) ) + 1
```

Comment: What result are you getting with this? Is this a measure or a column?

Comment: LPO_Date and CLM_Intm_DT is columns

Comment: I believe you overcomplicate things, when you need an extra column, you can write: V_TurnArount Time = LPO_excel[LPO_DATE] - Claims_excel[CLM_INTM_DT]. Note: you need a 1:1 relation between your tables..

Comment: when i try this this shows an error "Cannot find name" and red underline on both columns

Comment: @Aldert is correct. You are either creating a measure, not a column or (which is more likely) you are working with multiple tables, which have no relationships between them. Provide sample data so we can help you further or check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/related-function-dax

Comment: can you post a shot of your model ?

Comment: this is link model. https://www.dropbox.com/s/52j0s8rn0ze0mci/Claims_test_model.pbix?dl=0  .. in this please check variables table and in that check  v_TurnAround_Time measure ..

Comment: @StelioK .......

Comment: @Pavel Klammert

Comment: @Aldert.........

Comment: Please be aware that we are working in different timezones and that this is a site where there are zero commitments (all free of charge). It is considered rude when you start pushing others for answers. I will have a look later.

Comment: oh sorry for this .. and yes please check model and let me know

Comment: after looking at the model and the columns, I have to ask what is it, that you want to accomplish actually? Both the columns are dates and subtraction might do something different, then you expect. Because simply using your formula, I get list of dates in the year 1900 and I doubt that is what you are after

Comment: i am trying to get days

Comment: any solutions ?? i am trying to get just different between two days and want days

Comment: I think you are looking for this https://dax.guide/datediff/
But be carefull with relationships. If you using two tables it will be different a solution of a new column in many side than solution of new column in one side.